# NativeModules.RNRadar is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

Even though, I have ran the command and linked the native dependencies. I'm getting this run time error:
**NativeModules.RNRadar is undefined**

```
react-native link react-native-radar
```

Ran Twice to check:

```
D:\react-native-project\radar>react-native link react-native-radar
Scanning folders for symlinks in D:\react-native-project\radar\node_modules (46ms)
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-radar is already linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-radar is already linked
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Manually Linking ,
react native link is known to have issues

Comment: https://github.com/radarlabs/react-native-radar Does not have guidelines for manual linking. :/

Comment: there is line mentioned in the repo " If you do not install the native dependencies, you will get an error at run time: NativeModules.RNRadar is undefined". 
So i guess adding tha native components documentation can be found here https://radar.io/documentation/sdk#android

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by reinstalling the app.